# What is the name of this video game?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, video-games

This is a little riddle about a mobile video game.

> Bounce to the music
>   Jump on little orbs
>   Make your own levels
>   Design em', if you're bored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the game that is clued at here is...

> **[Geometry Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_Dash)**!
>
>  *Bounce to the music*
>  Most levels involve tapping/jumping to the music.
>
>  *Jump on little orbs*
>  In the game, you typically [jump on orbs](https://geometry-dash.fandom.com/wiki/Transporters#Rings) to bounce.
>
>  *Make your own levels; Design em', if you're bored*
>  The game also features [its own level editor](https://geometry-dash.fandom.com/wiki/Level_Editor).

Comment: YEP! that's right! gotta wait to accept an answer though.

Comment: Woohoo! I haven't answered one in a while since I keep getting sniped. I'm glad I opened PSE at the right time!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

> The game is Mario maker!(I believe)

because

> Mario maker has music, and it compels you to get through
> Making levels, and playing them )
> Switches and clouds and orbs in mario maker

Although it could also be

> Geometry dash

since I dont believe the first answer is on mobile.

Comment: please explain your approach to this answer. thanks and happy puzzling ;)